# On-collision script not working?

Tags: c#, collision-detection, collision, unity-game-engine

in advanced I would like to say if this is a really simple question with a simple answer, I apologize as I have just now gotten into programming.Basically, I'm trying to create a script that a block named blue(picture below) on collision with the FPSController, will get destroyed, here is my script:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Cube : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col) {

        if(col.gameObject.name == "Blue") {

            Destroy(col.gameObject);
            print ("collison detected");

        }

    }

}
```

for some reason, though, whenever the fps controller collides with the object known as "Blue" nothing happens, the print() function is not triggered nor is the destroy() function
[image]

Thank you in advaned **;)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rigidbody` is missing from your Cubes.

**1**.Attach `Rigidbody` component to both cubes.

**2**.Also,set both Cubes `Rigidbody` to Is-kinematic. You must set both Cubes `Rigidbody` to Is-kinematic so that the Character Controller wont be able to move it. Note that if your cube is falling down after adding `Rigidbody`, simply disable `Use Graivty` on the `Rigidbody`.

Important:

**3**.Delete `FPSController`. Since you will be interacting with other `Rigidbody` GameObjects, use `RigidBodyFPSController`. It can be found in `Assets\Standard Assets\Characters\FirstPersonCharacter\Prefabs`. Drag `RigidBodyFPSController` to the Scene then attach Cube script to it.

You will notice there is a `Rigidbody` attached to `RigidBodyFPSController`. **Don't** modify the settings of it.

That's it. Everything should be working as expected.

`Cube` settings:

[image]

`RigidBodyFPSController` Settings:

[image]

Comment: I set "Blue" to a rigid body, have is Kinematic unchecked and "use gravity" unchecked, however the only change I'm seeing is the cube is falling after the FPScontroller touching it  btw here is image to show:  http://imgur.com/a/2BikD

Comment: **"I set "Blue" to a rigid body"** You don't set an object to a rigidbody, you attach a rigidbody to it. Can you attach Rigidbody to both objects?

Comment: I already have done  that i, have already tried changing which object gets the script as well

Comment: One object looks like this:http://imgur.com/a/B6xTu and the other looks like this http://imgur.com/a/HwGPr

Comment: @SpikyCat Re-wrote my answer after your new problem. It should be fine now. Just follow the steps to get it right.